# Is the an alternative to http_send_stream?

Tags: php

The function **http_send_stream** does not exist anymore in pecl_http 2.0

I am trying not to use pecl_http 2.0 since the documentation-situation on www.php.net is quite irritating (still targeted at pecl_http 1).

Now my question is: Is there a non pecl_http way to send a stream to the browser? (including support for **range-requests** just like http_send_stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on php.net is only about v1, that's right.

v2 of pecl_http is [documented elsewhere](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http) ([source](https://github.com/m6w6/mdref-http)).

Replacing [http_send_stream()](http://php.net/http_send_stream) with v2 would be quite simple:

```
<?php
use http\Env\Response;
use http\Message\Body;

$r = new Response;
$r->setBody(new Body($stream));
$r->send();
```

See:

- [http\Env\Response](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Env/Response)
- [http\Message](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Message)
- [http\Message\Body](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Message/Body)